# Java Perlin Noise Implementation Problems

Tags: java, persistence, frequency, noise, perlin-noise

Hey stackoverflow community! I have been reading about perlin noise for the past 2 weeks and tried implementing it on my own in the most basic way.  Even so, my program does not work.  It outputs near similar looking results all the time and the persistence does not seem to change anything.  Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Noise extends JPanel{

public static int octaves = 4;
public static int size =  128;
public static float[][][] noise = new float[size][size][octaves];
public static float[][] perlinnoise = new float[size][size];

public static float p = (float) 1/4;

public static Random gen = new Random();

public static float GenerateNoise() {
    return gen.nextFloat();
}

public static float SmoothNoise(int x, int y, int z) {
    try{
        float corners = (noise[x - 1][y - 1][z] + noise[x + 1][y - 1][z] + noise[x - 1][y + 1][z] + noise[x + 1][y + 1][z]) / 16;
        float sides = (noise[x - 1][y][z] + noise[x + 1][y][z] + noise[x][y - 1][z] + noise[x][y + 1][z]) / 8;
        float center = noise[x][y][z] / 4;
        return corners + sides + center;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static float InterpolatedNoise(float x, float y, int pX, int pY, int pZ) {
    int intX = (int) x;
    int intY = (int) y;
    float fracX = x - intX;
    float fracY = y - intY;
    float v1 = SmoothNoise(pX, pY, pZ);
    float v2 = SmoothNoise(pX + 1, pY, pZ);
    float v3 = SmoothNoise(pX, pY + 1, pZ);
    float v4 = SmoothNoise(pX + 1, pY + 1, pZ);
    float i1 = Interpolate(v1, v2, fracX);
    float i2 = Interpolate(v3, v4, fracX);
    return Interpolate(i1, i2, fracY);
}

public static float Interpolate(float a, float b, float x) {
    float ft = (float) (x * 3.1415927);
    float f = (float) ((1 - Math.cos(ft)) * 0.5);
    return (float) (a * (1 - f) + b * f);
}

public static float Perlin2D(float x, float y, int posX, int posY, int posZ) {
    float total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < octaves; i++) {
        double f = Math.pow(2, i);
        double a = Math.pow(p, i);
        total = (float) (total + InterpolatedNoise((float)(x * f), (float)(y * f), posX, posY, posZ) * a);
    }
    return total;
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    for(int z = 0; z < octaves; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                noise[x][y][z] = GenerateNoise();
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int z = 0; z < octaves; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
                perlinnoise[x][y] = Perlin2D(x / (size - 1), y / (size - 1), x, y, z) / octaves;
            }
        }
    }
    
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Perlin Noise");
    f.setSize(400, 400);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new Noise());
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            g.setColor(new Color(perlinnoise[x][y], perlinnoise[x][y], perlinnoise[x][y]));
            g.fillRect(x * 2, y * 2, 2, 2);
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
}
```

I do not understand why it is not working because it is exactly as the pseudo code in [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) article said to do it.  Can anyone assist me in figuring this out? Thanks.

EDIT:  Ok please can someone just explain the process required to do this PLEASE I am going crazy trying to figure this out.  I have been trying to figure it out for the past 2 weeks and no one is giving me any help with it. Please if you know how to do this, please just explain it to me I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: There's an implementation in Java at http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/noise/, you don't need to make your own.

Comment: I want to make my own though :)

Comment: You should step through your implementation and the reference implementation in a debugger, in order to discover where the behaviour diverges.

Comment: Ok I have tried that but my problem inlies where I interpolate and smooth but I do not know how to do this correctly because I do not understand this part of the process and have asked it many times

Comment: I noticed Ken's code does 3d noise. What if you want some 2d noise instead? Does he provide (somewhere) code for the less complex 2d noise - instead of calling his 3d noise with the same z value?